# Converting html table into ncurses-like ascii table?

Tags: shell-script, ncurses, lynx

I have some documentation in an html table. I want to convert the table to an ascii table, like you see when you get a mysql command line result back, like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| header     | header     |
+------------+------------+
| cell data  | cell data  |
+------------+------------+
| cell data  | cell data  |
+------------+------------+
```

... so I can include it in some code comments.

How could I do this easily? I was thinking piping the output of lynx into a file, but lynx doesn't put ascii borders around tables :P

I also want to control cell width, so that the content cells don't spill outside the accepted screen width of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are better off using [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) for table rendering:

```
links -width 80 -dump http://website.com/ > file.html
```

Comment: or [links 2](http://links.twibright.com/development.php) or [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) or [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). Try them all and see whose rendering you like best.

Comment: Yes, the version I tested with was actually links2

Comment: I tried both links2 and elinks, and did not get any border between cells. Could you please indicate whether you actually got them, and if so the version of links you used?

Comment: @anol with elinks on centos 6 this works
    `elinks -dump http://www.html.am/html-codes/tables`
however it depends if the table has borders configured itself